# QGIS clip raster by mask layer unreliable if opacity of mask layer is <100%

Tags: qgis

When I use the Clip Raster by Mask Layer to clip a DEM with a regular vector layer, it sometimes doesn't work if the opacity of the mask layer is below 100%. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. I don't understand why this could be happening. Using QGIS 3.22.2 on a Mac.

Comment: Do you get a error message? Does it work if you remove the opacity? Sounds like a bug

Comment: Can you share the data?